# Cargo Plane vs Jewelry S tore (Mad City)

Tags: roblox

In Roblox's mad city game, there are quite a few heists but I'm confused between the Jewelry Store and Cargo Plane heists. Both of them reward the same amount of cash (5k) so what's the big difference between them? Which one is better if I were to collect more cash?